# Are there any real & decent mathematics video games?

Tags: card-games, learning, motivation

Personally, I like to play video games from time to time, especially arcade games (e.g. Tetris, pinball) or fast-paced games like [Super Hexagon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeiMubg_MRA), which is known to be quite challenging.

However, for mathematics (that is not intended for kids) I have not found anything interesting so far.

What I am thinking about is a game where one has to do (increasingly difficult) calculus under a time constraints, with perhaps a 'health bar' that increase or decreases depending on how you are doing.
Perhaps with music, nice visuals or other such things.

Does someone have a suggestion along these lines?

Also, I did find this related but otherwise very different question:
[Is there any gamified software for learning advanced mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196105/is-there-any-gamified-software-for-learning-advanced-mathematics)

Comment: How blatantly "mathematical" do you want it to be?  You could argue that artillery games like WORMS or Scorched Earth are in fact exercises in projectile motion and differential equations.  You could argue that games like Qbert are exercises in graph theory and hamiltonian paths.  You could argue that any number of other games are exercises in game theory and probability... Most puzzle games can be categorized as math, especially sudoku and minesweeper.

Comment: You could also argue that Kerbal Space Programme is a math game, because you have to calculate the amount of fuel needed for a given mission, and numerous other things. I, at least, always take out a calculator when playing it.

Comment: Uhu, I see, well I would like it to have an 'arcade' flavor with speed as an important game element, like in Tetris or Super Hexagon, where inaction will be bad for you game-wise. When it comes to the "mathematical" part: If it would actually involve calculus, I would be very happy. Maybe something like https://www.wolframalpha.com/problem-generator/quiz/?category=Calculus&topic=IntegrateUSub, but in a more gamified form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something more complex , take a look at "Kerbal space program".

This game works on patched conics approximation

Some things in the game include 
*Flight planning - It is actually automatic but you can still try to mess around with your own calculations on fuel consumption 
 *Ideas of orbit transfer - This is not automatic ,you can use different types of pre-planned orbital manouvers ( which you can set during the journey ) or just calculate them.
*Using a mod called principia, which sets the game world into an n - body model ( see wiki "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation") .
N body model requires more complicated planning.

With all this , disable all the assistance by the game , and you are set into a really complicated physics game with complicated calculations.

Comment: I intended to answer the question before it was edited .